# How to use list comprehension on this for loop in python

Tags: python, list

I've just learned of list comprehension but I can't quite get it to work in the right context.
my for loop is:
results and instances are lists

```
for i in results:
    instances.remove(i)
    results.remove(i)
```

I tried `[i for i in one if one.count(i)<2 if two.count(i)<2]` but it doesn't work. I can get it to work on just one of them with this, `[i for i in one if one.count(i)<2]`, but I wanted to incorporate both of them into the same loop. Can someone show me the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Don't modify a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Your `for` loop probably isn't working properly either because you are modifying `results` while looping over it

Comment: Can you give us sample output and input?

Comment: Yes, I just found that out, but wouldn't it work using list comprehension?

Comment: Also, you don't seem to understand what LCs are for. They are just expression to create new lists, not modifying an existing one. They are not magic, everything you can do with them you can also be done inside a normal loop.

Comment: Maybe you can describe what you are trying to accomplish. It's hard to guess just from bits of code that don't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `results` is a list. You seem to be trying to do this

```
for i in results:
    instances.remove(i)
del results[:]
```

list comprehension is the wrong thing to use here. You're not trying to create a new list from a sequence.

This loops is similar, but will remove the instances in the reverse order

```
while results:
    instances.remove(results.pop())
```

Comment: @alKid, you don't necessarily want to rebind `results`

Comment: @gnibbler, thank you!! My code now works using that delete method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first take the results out of the for loop. Set it after it and then delete it once the for loop has finished.